# Magento 2: How to add title tag in product image in product details page?

Tags: seo, magento2.2.3, title

How to add title tag in product image in product details page?

**current img tag in product detail page**

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="hello" class="fotorama__img" aria-hidden="false">
```

**I want to add title tag like:**

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="hello" title="hello" class="fotorama__img" aria-hidden="false">
```

Please let me know any suggestion to do this.

Comment: Do you want to add a caption to the Image ?

Comment: I want to add title, not caption.

Comment: Did you find the way to add title? I have the same problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158529)

Answer (score 0):

The title-tag is good for nothing. Yes google themselves say to add a title to the image.
Unfortunately most seo specialists have no idea what they are doing and didn't get that google does not talk about the title-tag at all.
Google specifically states that you need to provide the alt-tag!

> Lastly, optimizing your image filenames and alt text makes it easier for image search projects like Google Image Search to better understand your images.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184

Comment: Btw. I used your wording, but `title` and `alt` are actually attributes not a tags.

Answer (score 0):

You want to bring image_with_borders.phtml template file into your theme.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml

Then it's something like this

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image */ ?>

<span class="product-image-container"
      style="width:<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getWidth()) ?>px;">
    <span class="product-image-wrapper"
          style="padding-bottom: <?= ($block->getRatio() * 100) ?>%;">
        <img class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getClass()) ?>"
            <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getCustomAttributes()) ?>
            src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getImageUrl()) ?>"
            max-width="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getWidth()) ?>"
            max-height="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getHeight()) ?>"
            alt="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getLabel(), null, true) ?>
            title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getLabel(), null, true) ?>"/></span>
</span>
```

Uses image label.  But that might be safer?

But if you want product name try

`$block->getProduct()->getName();`

but if that doesnt work

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('product');
$name = $product ? $product->getName() : null;
```

Which isn't perfect but close enough.

The better solution would be to modify Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image in an extension and then inject registry

https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-get-current-product-information/

Answer (score 0):

Need to update footerma.js file

/lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js  on Line 2425

```
if (frameData.data.caption) {
    img.alt = frameData.data.caption || "";
    img.title = frameData.data.caption || "";  /* Add this line for set title tag */ 
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Not sure if there is a solution that does not overwrite a lib-file directly but if I find one I will post it here.

Comment: I found a better way of overwriting this file, see my separate response.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer about editing the
*/lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js* file works, but I found out that you can actually copy the file to the following location before overwriting it:

*app/design/frontend/$Vendor/$Theme/web/fotorama/fotorama.js*

Afterwards, add third line as described in the other answer after line 2425:

```
if (frameData.data.caption) {
    img.alt = frameData.data.caption || "";
    img.title = frameData.data.caption || ""; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I don't want to copy the whole fotorama.js file in my template, I came up with another solution:

```
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'mage/gallery/gallery'], function($, gallery){
        $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').on('gallery:loaded', function () {
            $(this).on('fotorama:load', function(){
                    document.querySelectorAll('.fotorama__img').forEach(image => {
                    image.setAttribute('title',image.getAttribute('alt'));
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have added this code in a `before.body.end` block in catalog product view.